# How to handle missing data in machine learning

Tags: missing-data

1. i know how to find and fill the missing values. But i am not sure when to fill the values with min., max. , mean, median or mode. Can someone help me to understand on what basis i can decide , i have to remove the missing rows or columns and if i have to keep the missing data on what basis i can fill the missing values.
2. how i can fill the missing data in categorical feature?

Comment: Are you using R or Python?

Comment: I am using python

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated question. I recommend the book by little and Rubin statistical analysis with missing data.
https://books.google.com/books/about/Statistical_Analysis_with_Missing_Data.html

Basically, there are three categories of missing data. We assume that
each data record can be divided into an "observable component" and an
"unobservable component". We also assume that the data records are independent
and identically distributed.

- MCAR (Missing Completely At Random) where the pattern of missinginess
  is statistically independent of the data record. Example: you have a data
  set on a piece of paper and you spill coffee on the paper destroying part
  of the data.
- MAR (Missing At Random) where the probability distribution of the pattern of missingness is functionally dependent upon the observable component in the record. MCAR is a special case of MAR. Example: you have a question on a survey
  asking if the survey participant is a drug addict and another question which 
  asks if the survey participant has less than one alcoholic drink per year. 
  Assume the answer to the alcoholic drink question is always observable, then
  the probability that someone fails to answer the drug addict question is
  most likely functionally dependent upon their answer to the alcoholic drink
  question.
- MNAR (Missing Not at Random) which is defined as the case which is NOT MAR.
  In the MNAR case, you can have situations where both the drug addict and alcoholic drink questions are absent in the same record. Another example,
  is a case where the question is: "What is your gender?" Suppose that females
  are less likely to answer this question than males. This is another example
  of an MNAR question because the probability that the answer is observable
  is conditionally dependent upon the unobservable component of the data record.

**Ok...now that we have some terminology, we can discuss some strategies and
recommendations...**

- 1) Never insert mean, mode,mean, max, min, median, or anything else for missing values. That is avoid deterministic imputation even though it is widely used and available in most software packages. It underestimates and distorts the statistical regularities (e.g., underestimates variance is one example) present in your data sample. In some special cases such as linear regression it might have some limited value but in general I wouldn't mess with it.

  - 2) if the data records are MCAR Then you can delete records with missing data.
  - 3) if the data records are MCAR, then sometimes you can
    stochastically impute the missing values rather than
    deterministically impute them. So this means that if you specify the
    marginal probability distribution of a missing value as Gaussian
    with some known mean and some known variance then you can sample
    from that distribution to impute values into the data set. You need
    to be careful here and do some additional research beyond this
    answer before moving forward with this.
  - 4) If the data is MAR then an algorithm such as Expectation    Maximization can be used to handle the missing observations.
  - 5) If the data is MNAR you can include binary indicators in the data    record which explicitly identify when a variable is not
    observable.    The challenge with this approach is that a highly
    nonlinear model    needs to be designed to properly integrate this
    information in an    appropriate manner. This might work in a machine
    learning algorithm    where the binary indicators "disconnect" the
    influence of predictors    which are not observable. Consequently,
    the MNAR theory (i.e., the    theory of the joint distribution of the
    complete data record and    missing data pattern) is instantiated in
    the learning machine's    probabilistic model of its statistical
    environment.